# How to bind to attribute in Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js

I got this error

> Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the
>   colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of `<div id="{{ val }}">`,
>   use `<div :id="val">`.

on this line

```
<a href="/Library/@Model.Username/{{myVueData.Id}}">
```

It works in Angular 1. How do you do it in Vue?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In your template:

```
<a :href="href">
```

And you put `href` in `data`:

```
new Vue({
  // ...
  data: {
    href: 'your link'
  }
})
```

Or use a computed property:

```
new Vue({
  // ...
  computed: {
    href () {
      return '/foo' + this.someValue + '/bar'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you CodinCat, I believe computed property is the answer. I just wished Vue could come up with something better. This will be tedious for all the href's and image src's :(

Comment: If you have several `href`s need to be computed in a same pattern, use methods

Comment: like `getHref (id) { return '/foo/' + id }`

Comment: will  <a :href="{{ href }}"> also be the same thing?

Comment: @doga No, it's not valid template syntax at all. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

Comment: @CodinCat how about <a :href="{{ href }}"> ?

Answer (score 5):

Just complementing ... solve the interpolation error (simple solution, I am Junior front-end developer):
Example post object in a loop:

- instead of

```
    <a href="{{post.buttonLinkExt}}">
```

- try this way

```
    <a v-bind:href="post.buttonLinkExt">
```

Answer (score 4):

Use javascript code inside `v-bind` (or shortcut ":") :

```
:href="'/Library/@Model.Username' + myVueData.Id"
```

and

```
:id="'/Library/@Model.Username' + myVueData.Id"
```

**Update Answer**

Some directives can take an “argument”, denoted by a colon after the directive name. For example, the `v-bind` directive is used to reactively update an HTML attribute:

```
<a v-bind:href="url"></a>
```

Here `href` is the argument, which tells the `v-bind` directive to bind the element’s `href` attribute to the value of the expression url. You may have noticed this achieves the same result as an attribute interpolation using `href="{{url}}"`: that is correct, and in fact, attribute interpolations are translated into `v-bind` bindings internally.

Answer (score 2):

Found in Google this topic when searching `$attrib`.
Question don't specify what value is used (maybe not defined before) 
For ANY parent attribute or to FILTER it, use something like that:

```
<template>
  <component
    is="div"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    class="bg-light-gray"
  >
  EXAMPLE
  </component>
</template>
```

This instruct to create specific, dynamic and context aware, wrapper:

- `v-bind="$attrs"` instruct to take all sended params. Not needed to declare as param object in script.
- Work even with valid html attribute like `class`
- example above mix static class with parent and join it. Use ternary operator (x=1?x:y) to choose proper one.
- bonus: by "is" you can dynamically set tag like `header` or `secion` instead of `div`
- `$attrs` can be binded to any tag in component so this easily enable simple transmission for one tag dynamic attributes like you define class for `<input />` but wrapper and actions are added in component

Source with description: https://youtu.be/7lpemgMhi0k?t=1307

Answer (score 1):

you can either use the shorthand `:` or `v-bind`

```
<div>
    <img v-bind:src="linkAddress">
</div>

new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            linkAddress: 'http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/217/729/f9a.jpg'
        }
});
```

or for when you need more than just binding an attribute you can also do:

```
    new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                finishedLink: '<a href="http://google.com"> Google </a>' 
            }
    });
```