# Displaying a video in Laravel View

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a problem displaying a video in view using Laravel as backend and Vue Js as front end.
This is my code.
I am able to display the filename from the database using    `{{product.video[0].filename}}` but unable to translate this in this line src="'video2/...

This is the code

```
 {{product.video[0].filename}} //Here am able to display filename correctly from database

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="'video2/'+product.video[0].filename type="video/mp4">// This cant capture the 
                                                                           video from video folder.
</video>
```

But if I write   `<source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">` this works correctly but I want to capture using the exact name from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to bind the video `src` like this `:src`

```js
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source :src="'video2/'+product.video[0].filename" type="video/mp4">
    video from video folder.
</video>
```

ref links

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

[How to bind to attribute in Vue JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062149/how-to-bind-to-attribute-in-vue-js)