# Vue interpolation for key-value pairs

Tags: vue.js

Suppose that I have a data property in Vue.js called `iconsColor`, which is defined like this:

```
data() {
    return {
      iconsColor: "#b5ffff",
    };
  },
```

I want to be able to use this property where I am setting color like this:

```
:style="{ color: '#b5ffff' }"
```

I tried a couple of different ways

```
:style="{ color: '{{iconsColor}}' }"
```

and studied a few interpolation techniques like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062149/how-to-bind-to-attribute-in-vue-js) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211760/how-to-solve-interpolation-inside-attributes-has-been-removed-use-v-bind-or-the), but I was not able to come to a solution. How this utilization can happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this section](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#object-syntax-2) the style could be bound to the data property as follows :

```
:style="{ color: iconsColor }"
```